# what's wrong with this my rtsp methods? (server replies 459 always)

Tags: rtsp

Sorry for my bad english

i'm working to rtsp communicate program

this RTSP server replies 459 error(Aggregate Operation not Allowed) on my SETUP request

I have no idea of this.

please help me. What did I wrong?

```
==== Message Log =====

Connecting.

RequestMessage
DESCRIBE rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:554/racecar_300.wmv RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 2

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
X-Playlist-Gen-Id: 106
X-Broadcast-Id: 0
Content-Length: 5220
Date: Sun, 12 Feb 2012 23:02:31 GMT
CSeq: 2
Server: WMServer/9.5.6001.18281
Supported: com.microsoft.wm.srvppair, com.microsoft.wm.sswitch, com.microsoft.wm.eosmsg, com.microsoft.wm.fastcache, com.microsoft.wm.packetpairssrc, com.micros
oft.wm.startupprofile
Last-Modified: Tue, 22 Jan 2008 22:54:32 GMT
Cache-Control: x-wms-content-size=1222202, max-age=86399, must-revalidate, proxy
-revalidate
Etag: "1222202"

v=0
o=- 201202072042160228 201202072042160228 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=Racecar WM 9 Series 300kbps
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:315
a=maxps:1518
t=0 0
a=control:rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:554/racecar_300.wmv/
a=etag:{67F94DEE-D1E6-A9AF-31C6-64D39ADB876E}
a=range:npt=3.000-34.064
a=recvonly
a=pgmpu:data:application/x-wms-contentdesc,8,language,31,0,,5,title,31,27,Raceca
r%20WM%209%20Series%20300kbps,6,author,31,21,Microsoft%20Corporation,9,copyright,31,57,Copyright%20(C)%20Microsoft%20Corporation.%20All%20rights%20reserved.,44,WMS_CONTENT_DESCRIPTION_SERVER_BRANDING_INFO,31,12,WMServer/9.5,51,WMS_CONTENT_DESCRIPTION_PLAYLIST_ENTRY_START_OFFSET,3,4,3000,47,WMS_CONTENT_DESCRIPTION_PLAYLIST_ENTRY_DURATION,3,5,31064,58,WMS_CONTENT_DESCRIPTION_COPIED_METADATA_FROM_PLAYLIST_FILE,3,1,1,42,WMS_CONTENT_DESCRIPTION_PLAYLIST_ENTRY_URL,31,15,racecar_300.wmv%0D%0A
a=pgmpu:data:application/vnd.ms.wms-hdr.asfv1;base64,MCaydY5mzxGm2QCqAGLObHQLAAAAAAAACAAAAAECMyaydY5mzxGm2QCqAGLObPoAAAAAAAAAOA
AsAHQAAAAAAFIAYQBjAGUAYwBhAHIAIABXAE0AIAA5ACAAUwBlAHIAaQBlAHMAIAAzADAAMABrAGIAcABzAAAATQBpA
GMAcgBvAHMAbwBmAHQAIABDAG8AcgBwAG8AcgBhAHQAaQBvAG4AAABDAG8AcAB5AHIAaQBnAGgAdAAgACgAQwApACAA
TQBpAGMAcgBvAHMAbwBmAHQAIABDAG8AcgBwAG8AcgBhAHQAaQBvAG4ALgAgAEEAbABsACAAcgBpAGcAaAB0AHMAIAB

yAGUAcwBlAHIAdgBlAGQALgAAAKHcq4xHqc8RjuQAwAwgU2VoAAAAAAAAAK8o5Xb3qPZEhHWICQOCKtI6phIAAAAAAN
B8E2B0p8IBIwMAAAAAAAAAwU0UAAAAANCbnxIAAAAAuAsAAAAAAAACAAAA7gUAAO4FAAC2zAQAtQO/Xy6pzxGO4wDAD
CBTZUUHAAAAAAAAEdLTq7qpzxGO5gDADCBTZQYAFwcAAKlGQ3zg7/xLsik5Pt5BXIUnAAAAAAAAAAEADGUAbgAtAHUA
cwAAAF2L8SaERexHn18OZR8EUskaAAAAAAAAAAIB6sv4xa9bd0iEZ6qMRPpMymIBAAAAAAAABgAAAAEADAACAAIAAAB
JAHMAVgBCAFIAAAAAAAAAAQA0AAAABgAAAEQAZQB2AGkAYwBlAEMAbwBuAGYAbwByAG0AYQBuAGMAZQBUAGUAbQBwAG
wAYQB0AGUAAABMADEAAAAAAAIADAACAAIAAABJAHMAVgBCAFIAAAAAAAAAAgA0AAAADAAAAEQAZQB2AGkAYwBlAEMAb
wBuAGYAbwByAG0AYQBuAGMAZQBUAGUAbQBwAGwAYQB0AGUAAABNAFAAQABMAEwAAAAAAAEALgADAAQAAABXAE0ALwBX
AE0AQQBEAFIAQwBQAGUAYQBrAFIAZQBmAGUAcgBlAG4AYwBlAAAAOnwAAAAAAQA0AAMABAAAAFcATQAvAFcATQBBAEQ
AUgBDAEEAdgBlAHIAYQBnAGUAUgBlAGYAZQByAGUAbgBjAGUAAAD5LAAAdNQGGN/KCUWkupqry5aq6IgEAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADLpeYUcsYyQ4OZqWlSBltaWAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKPoAALgLAAAAAAAAKPoAALgLAAAAAAAAzwUAAAIAAAABAAAAniwZAAAAAAAAAAAAy6XmFH
LGMkODmalpUgZbWm4AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPiVAwC4CwAAAAAAAPiVAwC4CwAAAAAAACo2AAACAAAAA
gAAAJpbBgAAAAAAAAABAFCUvcZ/hgdJg6PHeSG3M60CAAAAAAAg3qrZF3ycT7wohVXdmOKiJgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAECk0NIH49IRl/AAoMleqFCiAAAAAAAAAAMAHABXAE0ARgBTAEQASwBWAGUAcgBzAGkAbwBuAAAAAAAaADk
ALgAwADAALgAwADAALgAyADkAOAAwAAAAGgBXAE0ARgBTAEQASwBOAGUAZQBkAGUAZAAAAAAAFgAwAC4AMAAuADAALg
AwADAAMAAwAAAADABJAHMAVgBCAFIAAAACAAQAAAAAAEBS0YYdMdARo6QAoMkDSPbwAAAAAAAAAEFS0YYdMdARo6QAo
MkDSPYCAAAAAgAWAFcAaQBuAGQAbwB3AHMAIABNAGUAZABpAGEAIABBAHUAZABpAG8AIAA5AAAAKgAgADYANAAgAGsA
YgBwAHMALAAgADQANAAgAGsASAB6ACwAIABzAHQAZQByAGUAbwAgACgAQQAvAFYAKQAgADEALQBwAGEAcwBzACAAQwB
CAFIAAAACAGEBAQAWAFcAaQBuAGQAbwB3AHMAIABNAGUAZABpAGEAIABWAGkAZABlAG8AIAA5AAAAAQAAAAQAV01WM5
EH3Le3qc8RjuYAwAwgU2VyAAAAAAAAAECeafhNW88RqP0AgF9cRCtQzcO/j2HPEYuyAKoAtOIgAAAAAAAAAAAcAAAAC
AAAAAEAzPbPAmEBAgBErAAARR8AAM8FEAAKAACIAAAPAHkuAAABzwXPBQEAAJEH3Le3qc8RjuYAwAwgU2WFAAAwAAAA
AAMDvGbxNW88RqP0AgF9cRCsAV/sgVVvPEaj9AIBfXEQrAAAAAAAAAAA3AAAAAAAAAAIAeDdKAUABAACwAAAAAiwALA
AAAEABAACwAAAAAQAYAFdNVjMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEw5GgHOdfh7jUbREY2CAGCXyaKyJgAAAAAAAAACA
AEAUgYBAAIAZMYDADYmsnWOZs8RptkAqgBizmy8mRIAAAAAAK8o5Xb3qPZEhHWICQOCKtIjAwAAAAAAAAEB

m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 96
b=AS:68
b=X-AV:65
b=RS:0
b=RR:0
a=rtpmap:96 x-asf-pf/1000
a=control:audio
a=stream:1
m=application 0 RTP/AVP 96
b=RS:0
b=RR:0
a=rtpmap:96 x-wms-rtx/1000
a=control:rtx
a=stream:65536
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
b=AS:248
b=X-AV:235
b=RS:0
b=RR:0
a=rtpmap:96 x-asf-pf/1000
a=control:video
a=stream:2

RequestMessage
SETUP rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:554/racecar_300.wmv RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 3
Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=4568:4569

RTSP/1.0 459 Aggregate Operation Now Allowed
Date: Sun, 12 Feb 2012 23:02:31 GMT
CSeq: 3
Server: WMServer/9.5.6001.18281
Supported: com.microsoft.wm.srvppair, com.microsoft.wm.sswitch, com.microsoft.wm.eosmsg, com.microsoft.wm.fastcache, com.microsoft.wm.packetpairssrc, com.microsoft.wm.startupprofile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are implementing your own RTSP client, have you read and reread [RFC 2326: RTSP Spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2326.txt) as well as [RFC 4566: SDP Spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4566)? Also it appears you are integrating with Windows Media Server, so [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc245238%28PROT.10%29.aspx) is another good place to start.

RTSP protocol is based around sessions, each one identified by a unique URL. A session will always have one or more presentation streams (e.g. audio, video, subtitles...). Presentation streams are identified by an additional "a:control=..." suffix that is tacked onto the URL for the session itself.

Certain commands operate at a session level, other commands work with presentation streams, some commands might do either one.  The SETUP command ONLY works with presentation streams, so you are getting back an error because you are trying to access the session.  Each presentation stream will end up on its own RTP stream and they must be setup separately.

So in your case if you want video stream, you should be sending:

```
SETUP rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:554/racecar_300.wmv/video RTSP/1.0
```

Comment: Also `Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=4568:4569` should be `Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=4568-4569`